# mvc 4 controller ajax route

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-ajax

I have my controller like this

```
 public ActionResult DaySelect(SomeModel m)
    { table s= {eventid= m.eveid,dayno=m.dayno}
      return value; }
```

My ajax is like this

```
  var eveid=100;
  var dayno =10;
  var url = base_url + 'Event/DaySelect/' + eveid + "/" + dayno + "/";

    $.post(url, {}, function (data) {
        // somedata
         });
```

My question is how can i pass the ajax url like this, whether there is some place to route? when i pass like this i get error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use @Url.Action() helper for getting action url:

```
var url = '@Url.Action("DaySelect", "Event")' + '/' + eveid + '/' + dayno + '/';
```